# FILE IO, tokenizing a string

Tags: c, file-io, segmentation-fault, token

im trying to read a comma delimited file, and create tokens by the comma delimeter and printing names. but the names do not print after tokenize.

names.csv looks like

```
issac,sanchez
anothony,huerta
abbie,lynn
mark,beasly
alyssa,emily
```

my current code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE* fp;
    char buffer[100];
    fp = fopen("names.csv","r");

    while(fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fp) != NULL)
        printf("%s\n",buffer); 
    /*OUTPUT issac,sanchez
             anthony,huerta
             abbie,lynn...etc so buffer is a string??*/


    char* del = ",";
    char* token;
    token = strtok(buffer,del);
    while(token != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n",token);
        token = strtok(NULL,del);
    }

}
```

Comment: is it maybe because buffer is a string literal and i cannot tokenize it?

Comment: There should be more warnings, something like “implicit declaration of strtok”… In other words: Include `<string.h>`. And use a C99 conforming compiler.

Comment: And no, `buffer` is not a literal, it's a variable. And it points to a modifiable string.

Comment: thanks, i get no errors but the tokens dont print. Any idea at a quick glance?

Comment: that while loop is reading to the end of the file and so buffer will be empty after the last loop. YOu probably mean to put the strtok and all its code inside the loop

Answer (score 2):

If I don't `#include <string.h>`, the program segfaults. Otherwise, it works, printing `alyssa` on one line and `emily` on another.

gcc output without `#include <string.h>` using -Wall and -std=c99 flags:

```
names.c:16:2: warning: implicit declaration of function `strtok` [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
names.c:16:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
names.c:19:9: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

Lines 16 and 19 are the ones with `strtok` being called. Since undeclared functions are assumed to return an `int` by default, and `token` is a pointer, the warnings are raised.

On my machine, `sizeof(int) != sizeof(char *)`, which leads to incorrect code being generated; only 4 bytes are stored into the `token` pointer and later `printf` tries to read 8 bytes from `token` — 4 valid bytes from the 8-byte pointer returned by `strtok` and 4 random/unknown bytes, causing a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

`buffer` contains the result of the last successful read by fgets which may be a newline at the end of the file. The while loop body never executes. Fix: fseek to the beginning of the file, then start over.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> //for strtok

int main(void){
    FILE* fp;
    char buffer[100];
    const char *del = ",\n";

    fp = fopen("names.csv","r");

    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != NULL){
        //printf("%s\n", buffer); 
        char* token  = strtok(buffer, del);
        while(token != NULL){
            printf("%s\n", token);
            token = strtok(NULL, del);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}
```